# Using phpdesktop on a Laravel project, how can i run my own server?

Tags: laravel, server, phpdesktop

I am using phpdesktop on my Laravel project to create an exe file. In settings.json i have set up that phpdesktop is listening localhost:8000, but I can not start exe file without server previously runned (either php or artisan command). Is there any way that i can start my own local server before the module starts listening for localhost:80, something like put an exec command at the beginning of index.php?

Comment: could you use a different port?

Comment: suppose i could